# launch video when clicked upon a button - Android

Tags: java, android, button, video, android-videoview

Hej!

I want to create a program that has 3 buttons. Each button launches a new activity (videoview) that automatically plays a video from my res/raw folder when started. The code below does not display any errors, but is just not working, i.e. it launches the videoview but doesn´t display any video.

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}

public void playsquirrelmp4(View v) {
    Intent VideoIntent = (new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class));
    VideoIntent.putExtra("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.squirrel, uri);
    startActivity(VideoIntent);
}
```

My VideoActivity that plays the video

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

VideoView vid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

    vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();

    String uri = myIntent.getStringExtra("uri");
            Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();

    b.getString(uri);

}

public void startVideo(String uriString) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    vid.requestFocus();
    vid.setVideoURI(uri);
    vid.start();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `startVideo` in the `onCreate` method of the VideoActivity and then if you don't want the video start automatically pause it.

Also if you are testing on emulator, some times i had problem with videoView, but on real devices it always worked fine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the same key for your intent extra in the sender and receiver side.
 Change it as follows:

```
public void playsquirrelmp4(View v) {
    Intent VideoIntent = (new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class));
    VideoIntent.putExtra("uri", "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.squirrel, uri);
    startActivity(VideoIntent);
}
```

Your startVideo() method is not called therefore you can not expect the video to start.
Try the following instead!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

    vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();

    String uri = myIntent.getStringExtra("uri");
            Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();

    startVideo( b.getString(uri) ); // call startVideo here

}
```

Comment: from the debug info, it seems that the VideoIntent from the MainActivity cannot send the path of the video to VideoActivity. I get the an NullPointerException error from the uriString.

Answer (score 1):

from the debug info, it seems that the VideoIntent from the MainActivity cannot send the path of the video to VideoActivity. I get the an NullPointerException error from the uriString. I think some of that code from

VideoActivity

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
String uri = myIntent.getStringExtra("uri");
Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();

startVideo(b.getString(uri));
```

cannot receive the uri from Mainactivity:

```
    public void playsquirrelmp4(View v) {
    Intent VideoIntent = (new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class));
    VideoIntent.putExtra("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
    + "/"+   R.raw.squirrel, uri);
    startActivity(VideoIntent);
}
```